# Ionic Framework and Mobile Web

Tags: mobile, web, web-applications, ionic-framework

**The problem:** build a somewhat complex form that submits data to MySQL+PHP back-end. Requirements include:

- Accessible from browsers running on mobiles, tablets and desktops
- Must be completely platform independent; works well on Edge, Safari, Chrome, and other modern browsers.
- Must be implemented so that in the future, native versions can be implemented using the same code-base.

Based on my research, Ionic seems to be the best fit. However, I don't see anything about using Ionic for web-apps on their official website.

**Questions:**

1. Can Ionic be used to meet the above requirements? If yes, what is the best way to use Ionic for web-apps? Is there an official guideline from Ionic for this?
2. How else would you go about meeting the above requirements if not using Ionic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionic is built for developing mobile apps / progressive web apps. If you are looking for something which can be accesses through browsers `Angular` is the best option. [Progressive web apps](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/progressive-web-apps/) also will be something you can look  into. Except for native functionalities in mobile and routing in browsers , angular code will be reusable.

Comment: Thanks! This pointed me to the right direction. I will go with PWA.